# How do I append ndarray to a list and access the each stored ndarray from the list?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, append, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to create a list that store all ndarrays generated from my for loop:

```
for index in range(len(fishim)):
    cropped_fishim = []
    cropped_image = crop_img(fishim[index], labeled)#call function here.
    cropped_fishim.append(cropped_image)
```

Then I want to use `cropped_fishim[index]` to access the each stored `ndarray` for further process. I have also tried to use `extend` instead of `append` method. The `append` method packed all `ndarray` as one array and does not allow me to access each individual `ndarray` stored in `cropped_fishim`. The extend method does store `ndarray` separately, but `cropped_fishim[index]` would only access the `index`th col array. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Side-note: `for index in range(len(someseq)):` is an anti-pattern when the index is used solely to index `someseq`. This code could be simplified to just `for fish in fishim:` with references to `fishim[index]` becoming `fish` (`fish` could be changed to something more descriptive; I was guessing from limited context). It's faster, clearer, and more flexible (it would continue to work if `fishim` was any iterable type, not just sequences like `list` or `tuple`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append` is correct; your problem is in the line above it:

```
for index in range(len(fishim)):
    cropped_fishim = []
    cropped_image = crop_img(fishim[index], labeled)#call function here.
    cropped_fishim.append(cropped_image)
```

Each time through the loop, you reset the variable to `[]`, then append the new image array to that empty list.

So, at the end of the loop, you have a list containing just one thing, the last image array.

To fix that, just move the assignment before the loop, so you only do it once instead of over and over:

```
cropped_fishim = []
for index in range(len(fishim)):
    cropped_image = crop_img(fishim[index], labeled)#call function here.
    cropped_fishim.append(cropped_image)
```

However, once you’ve got this working, you can simplify it.

You almost never need—or want—to loop over `range(len(something))` in Python; you can just loop over `something`:

```
cropped_fishim = []
for fishy in fishim:
    cropped_image = crop_img(fishy, labeled)#call function here.
    cropped_fishim.append(cropped_image)
```

And then, once you’ve done that, this is exactly he pattern of a list comprehension, so you can optionally collapse it into one line:

```
cropped_fishim = [crop_img(fishy, labeled) for fishy in fishim]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Thanks!

easy trick learned:

```
cropped_fishim = [None]*len(fishim)

for index in range(len(fishim)):
    cropped_image = crop_img(fishim[index], labeled)#call function here.
    cropped_fishim[index] = cropped_image
```

Comment: By and large, preallocating a `list` with `None`s like that is considered unPythonic; repeated `append`s remove the risk of the presizing getting out of sync with the loop that replaces the placeholder values. The original code was trivially fixable just by moving the creation of the empty `list` outside the loop body, there is no real benefit to presizing the `list`.

Comment: While this works, it really isn’t a good solution. Better to use `append`, but just do it properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great inputs from you all!!